# Is it true that if $\kappa < \kappa^\nu$, then ${\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)} \leq \nu$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let $\kappa$ denote an infinite cardinal number. Then we know the following. $$\kappa<\kappa^{\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)}$$

**Question.** Is it true that if $$\kappa < \kappa^\nu,$$ then ${\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)} \leq \nu$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not true at all.

Consider the case $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$ and take $\kappa=\aleph_1$ and $\nu=\aleph_0$.

Comment: Any ideas about the following? Question: if we assume $\kappa$ is a beth number (which it is not in your counterexample), does $κ<κ^ν$ imply $\mathrm{cf}(κ)≤ν$?

Comment: I once referred you to a book called Introduction to Cardinal Arithmetic, and you can find this in Theorem 1.7.3.

Comment: Thank you. Yes its on my "buy asap" list on amazon, but I'm just absurdly broke at the moment. And the google books version is basically unusable, unfortunately.

Comment: There are other options, you know. Not legals ones, but surely if you're broke you can look the other way.

Comment: By the previous discussion, the following is a weakening of GCH: $\tag*{}$$\tag*{}$

**Axiom.** (For all infinite cardinals $\kappa$ and $\nu$.) If $\kappa^\nu > \kappa$, then $\nu \geq \mathrm{cf}(\kappa)$. $\tag*{}$$\tag*{}$

I just noticed something cool: in fact, its equivalent to GCH. In particular, assume the above axiom, and suppose for a contradiction that $2^{\kappa}>\kappa^+.$ Then $(\kappa^+)^\kappa > \kappa^+$. So by the aforementioned axiom, $\kappa \geq \mathrm{cf}(\kappa^+)$, a contradiction.

Comment: (Wish I knew how to do smaller linebreaks.)

Comment: Cute. You can do... $\tag*{}$ Something like this.